# AFNetworking - Twitter OAuth Redirect URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, afnetworking, passport.js

I'm a web developer new to iOS development and I'm trying to tie over the client/server Twitter OAuth process over to an iPhone app.

I want use a passport Twitter strategy on a node.js server for my authentication. So in a web client setting I make a request to a twitter authorization URL I've set up on the server, and the server responds with a redirect that takes me to the Twitter Login page w/ the access token provided. This redirect URL is automatically handled by the passport Twitter strategy.

How do I create the same web redirect effect within the context of an app using AFNetworking. I know how to make a basic POST and GET requests, but is there some setting where AFNetworking can handle the server response by opening safari and redirecting to the link provided?

The code I provided below doesn't throw any errors, but I doesn't redirect...

iOS Code:

```
- (IBAction)twitterLogin:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Twitter Login");

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:@"http://54.148.118.153/auth/twitterX/" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

}
```

Node.js server code:

```
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;

// twitter authentication and login
app.get('/auth/twitterX', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

// handle callback after twitter has authenticated user
app.get('/auth/twitterX/callback',
    passport.authenticate('twitter',{
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/'
    }
));

// used to serialize user
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
   done(null, user.twitter_id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(twitter_id,done){
   connection.query('SELECT * from User_Twitter where id = '+twitter_id, function(err,rows){
      done(err,rows[0]);
   });
});

// passport Twitter protocol
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey:'G17pGaKQUYPPsy5o5H7siZvWj',
    consumerSecret:'qiTVnzHsIhWDqlkPd4vF2Xao7L9wvAh08YGpwOpXb5CowesqIb',
    callbackURL:'http://54.148.118.153/auth/twitterX/callback'
},
function(token, tokenSecret, profile,done){
    //Make code asynchronous - MySQL query won't fire until we have all data back from twitter
    process.nextTick(function(){

       //Do stuff with Twitter data 


    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce you to AFOAuth2Client, maintained by the same folks who maintain AFNetworking: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client

I am going to paste their example code documentation here:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"];
AFOAuth2Client *oauthClient = [AFOAuth2Client clientWithBaseURL:url clientID:kClientID secret:kClientSecret];

[oauthClient authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath:@"/oauth/token"
                                   username:@"username"
                                   password:@"password"
                                      scope:@"email"
                                    success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
                                        NSLog(@"I have a token! %@", credential.accessToken);
                                        [AFOAuthCredential storeCredential:credential withIdentifier:oauthClient.serviceProviderIdentifier];
                                    }
                                    failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                    }];
```

Check out that NSLog statement in that success block: once you get that token, you can replace that NSLog statement with whatever storage solution you want to keep the token on the client.

Also, if you have not checked it out yet, I would highly recommend you use CocoaPods as your go-to dependency manager. That way, with one line you can bring in a dependency like AFOAuth2Client: http://cocoapods.org